# Adding negative and positive numbers in a column of a dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as Follows whose values range from -100 to +100 with about 2000 column and 60000 rows. I want to add the negative values and positive values seperately, but the value it gives me is not right.My dataframe looks like:

```
-40.11814993    -42.32948849    -43.60532899    -44.5204376 -41.63980543
-22.37778647    -25.46700883    -27.81140156    -28.82498654    -25.35257089
7.686002395 5.269545374 2.654357646 1.929572443 4.904498013
17.73773603 15.68456051 14.07506837 13.69786317 14.47200364
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
56.72239048 53.39504497 52.53564149 47.32158272 43.41294833
59.792111   54.45067217 52.77495286 48.27796907 44.49740268
63.99660216 56.19211308 53.75103818 50.25612484 46.40220142
59.43969877 50.4747657  47.5165962  44.37596015 40.85330564
52.78043922 42.79880307 39.09252048 36.4381745  33.07448607
```

I used the following code, if anyone make correction, i want add by column:

```
trialdata=read.table('trial.csv',header=TRUE,sep=',')
frame=data.frame(trialdata[3:20])
negativesum=apply(frame<0, MARGIN=2, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
positivesum=apply(frame>0, MARGIN=2, FUN = sum, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: `frame<0` will give `True/False` matrix, not the values from `frame`.

Answer (score 1):

No need to use apply, try below:

```
#dummy dataframe
df <- 
read.table(text="-40.11814993    -42.32948849    -43.60532899    -44.5204376 -41.63980543
-22.37778647    -25.46700883    -27.81140156    -28.82498654    -25.35257089
7.686002395 5.269545374 2.654357646 1.929572443 4.904498013
17.73773603 15.68456051 14.07506837 13.69786317 14.47200364
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
56.72239048 53.39504497 52.53564149 47.32158272 43.41294833
59.792111   54.45067217 52.77495286 48.27796907 44.49740268
63.99660216 56.19211308 53.75103818 50.25612484 46.40220142
59.43969877 50.4747657  47.5165962  44.37596015 40.85330564
52.78043922 42.79880307 39.09252048 36.4381745  33.07448607")

#result
sum(df[df<0],na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] -342.047
sum(df[df>0],na.rm = TRUE)
#[1] 1328.735
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want columnwise sums (because you use the `apply(.., 2, ...)`), I would suggest the following (using a fake data):

```
set.seed(123)
frame <- matrix(sample(-100:100, 100, replace = TRUE), ncol = 10)
ind_pos <- which(frame>0, arr.ind = TRUE)
ind_neg <- which(frame<=0, arr.ind = TRUE)

data.frame(positive = tapply(frame[ind_pos], ind_pos[,2], sum), negative = tapply(frame[ind_neg], ind_neg[,2], sum))
   positive negative
1       319     -161
2       314     -267
3       345     -113
4       323     -248
5        72     -383
6       202     -338
7       280     -171
8       142     -293
9       346     -227
10      122     -293
```

Answer (score 1):

If we need to get columnwise sum, we could use either one of the apply family to get the output.  Here, we are using `vapply`, which would be a bit more faster.  (Using data from @zx8754's post)

```
 vapply(df, function(x)  c(sum(x[x>0], na.rm=TRUE), 
               sum(x[x<=0], na.rm=TRUE)), double(2L))
 #          V1       V2        V3        V4        V5
 #[1,] 318.15498 278.2655 262.40018 242.29725 227.61685
 #[2,] -62.49594 -67.7965 -71.41673 -73.34542 -66.99238
```

An option using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr) 
 summarise_each(df, funs(positive=sum(.[.>0], na.rm=TRUE), 
                       negative=sum(.[.<=0], na.rm=TRUE))) %>%
              gather(Var, Val) %>%
              separate(Var, c('Var1', 'Var2')) %>% 
              spread(Var1, Val)
 #     Var2        V1       V2        V3        V4        V5
 #1 negative -62.49594 -67.7965 -71.41673 -73.34542 -66.99238
 #2 positive 318.15498 278.2655 262.40018 242.29725 227.61685
```

Instead of one call to `summarise_each`, a shorter option would be to `bind_rows` after double `summarise_each`

```
 bind_rows(summarise_each(df, funs(positive=sum(.[.>0], na.rm=TRUE))), 
           summarise_each(df, funs(negative=sum(.[.<=0], na.rm=TRUE)))
  )
```